# Experiments on expectations formation

Tags: behavioral-economics, experimental-economics, rational-expectations, expectations, adaptive-learning

I was reading about the debate between rational expectations and adaptive expectations in some intermediate macro notes. One of the arguments given to discard the adaptive expectations hypothesis drew my attention. Let $p_t$ be our variable of interest, and $E^a_{t}[p_{t+k}]$ be the expectation of the value of the variable at time $t+k$ in the period $t$ by agents who have adaptive expectations. A simple model of such expectations was given like this:

$$E^a_{t}[p_{t+1}] = E^a_{t-1}[p_t] + \theta (p_t - E^a_{t-1}[p_t])$$

where $0 < \theta < 1$. That is, agents use the error in the previous period to adjust their expectations, but do so only partly.

One criticism given of this model was: if the values of $p$ increase exponentially, say from 2 to 4 to 8 to 16 and so on, and the initial expectation was lower than the true value, then the expectations would never catch up with the real value and agents will always underpredict. So, for example, it $\theta = 0.5$ and the initial expectation was 1, then the sequence of expectations would be 1, 1.5, 2.75, 5.375 and so on. The agents' expectations are going more and more out of line with the true value, which seems implausible in the long run. This argument was used to motivate the use of rational expectations.

While I understand the appeal of rational expectations for long run behaviour, I would still be interested to know how the expectations actually evolve and how do they converge to rational expectations in the long run, if they do? Do agents slowly keep reducing the errors? Do they overshoot in different directions before reaching the truth?

1. There must be experiments that track this, I feel. Can anyone refer such studies, where participants are asked to guess the value of an exponentially increasing variable like this or anything similar? And any findings on whether the patterns are robust to different decision-making environments?
2. Any models from, say, Behavioural Economics, that explain experimental findings regarding expectations well?

Comment: Pesaran's text "The Limits of RE" has a chapter or two on the use of surveys to test whether people really do have rational expectations. Other texts have them also. I'm not aware of any discussions-research on testing whether people have adaptive expectations.